# How to make Eclipse use the Formatter rules when indent with Ctrl+I

Tags: c, eclipse, indentation, auto-indent

I'm using eclipse based IDE (Espressif-IDE) to develope C based firmwares.

I've created a profile under:

Window->Preferences->C/C++->Code Style->Formatter

for formating the code. I've un-set the checkbox for `break statements` under Indentation in the profile. This is to prevent the indent of the break in switch cases. The formatter works as intended when I use Ctrl+Shift+F.

The problem is when I use Ctrl+I to auto indent part of the code. This always indents the break. Is there any place to customize the rules for Ctrl+I?

I've checked the prefernces and couldn't find anything there. I know that if I select part of the code, using Ctrl+Shift+F will format according the rule, but, I'm looking to see if the indention by Ctrl+I is customisable or not.